# Javascript - how to start forEach loop at some index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with alot of items, and I am creating a list of them. I was thinking of paginating the list. I wonder how can I start a `forEach` or `for` loop at some `index` in an array, that would be in my example the number of items in the list on each page, so that I don't need to iterate over the whole array in each loop?

```
arr.forEach(function (item) {
  someFn(item);
})


for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  someFn(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: why don't you `slice()` your Array to get the Items on the curent page `var offset = currentPage*itemsPerPage; arr.slice(offset, offset+itemsPerPage).forEach(someFn);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a copy of the array, by using [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The **`slice()`** method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```
array.slice(10, 20).forEach(someFn); // only for functions which respects API of forEach*
```

* [parameters for a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters)

Or you can start at a given index and end at a given index.

```
for (var i = 10, len = Math.min(20, arr.length); i < len; i++) {
    someFn(arr[i]);
}
```

With

```
Math.min(20, arr.length)
```

returns a value, if the array is smaller than the given value `20`. For example if the array has only index 0 ... 14, you get as result 15.

Comment: @Leff: Beware that if `someFn` allows multiple arguments, there's a big difference between your callback `forEach(function(item) { someFn(item); })` and Nina's `forEach(someFn)` above, because `forEach` passes multiple arguments to the function it calls. But if `someFn` only ever uses its first argument, Nina's is the way to go.

Comment: Bounds checks should be included on the `i` and `len` for the `for` loop. If the OP didn't understand how to start and stop an indexed loop where desired, then they likely wouldn't think of that either.

Comment: @squint, for `i`, i think it's not necessary, because the length check prevents from iterating non existent items.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Only exception would be if  `i` ends up being negative, but that's probably not too likely.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately `Array#forEach` iterates over every element in the given array, but you could apply a simple condition to determine to which elements (with specified index) apply the given function.

```
i > 3 ? someFn(item) : null;
^ if index more than 3 - call the function
```

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

function someFn(elem){
  console.log(elem);
}

arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
  return i > 3 ? someFn(item) : null;
})
```

Answer (score 5):

`forEach` doesn't offer that feature, no. So your choices are:

1. A simple `for` loop
2. Ignoring the indexes you don't want to handle (as in [Kind user's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295869/157247))
3. Using `slice` (as in [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295882/157247))
4. Writing your own function

Here's #4 as an `Array.prototype` extension (non-enumerable, of course; adding enumerable properties to `Array.prototype` breaks a **lot** of code); after it is a standalone version for when adding to `Array.prototype` isn't appropriate:

```js
// Giving ourselves the function
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "myEach", {
  value: function(from, to, callback, thisArg) {
    if (typeof from === "function") {
      thisArg = callback;
      callback = to;
      to = from;
      from = 0;
    }
    if (typeof to === "function") {
      thisArg = callback;
      callback = to;
      to = this.length;
    }
    for (var n = from; n < to; ++n) {
      callback.call(thisArg, this[n], n, this);
    }
  }
});

// Using it:
var arr = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];
console.log("*** From 3:");
arr.myEach(3, function(e) { console.log(e); });
console.log("*** From 3 (inclusive) to 5 (exclusive):");
arr.myEach(3, 5, function(e) { console.log(e); });
console.log("*** All:");
arr.myEach(function(e) { console.log(e); });
console.log("*** Check thisArg handling on 0-2:");
var o = {answer: 42};
arr.myEach(0, 2, function(e) {
  console.log(e + " (this.answer = " + this.answer + ")");
}, o);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Again note that that's a **non-enumerable** property, which is vital if you ever add anything to `Array.prototype` (otherwise, you break a lot of code).

You wouldn't do that in a library to be consumed by others, you'd just have a standalone function:

```js
// Giving ourselves the function
function myEach(array, from, to, callback, thisArg) {
  if (typeof from === "function") {
    thisArg = callback;
    callback = to;
    to = from;
    from = 0;
  }
  if (typeof to === "function") {
    thisArg = callback;
    callback = to;
    to = array.length;
  }
  for (var n = from; n < to; ++n) {
    callback.call(thisArg, array[n], n, array);
  }
}

// Using it:
var arr = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];
console.log("*** From 3:");
myEach(arr, 3, function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
console.log("*** From 3 (inclusive) to 5 (exclusive):");
myEach(arr, 3, 5, function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
console.log("*** All:");
myEach(arr, function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
console.log("*** Check thisArg handling on 0-2:");
var o = {answer: 42};
myEach(arr, 0, 2, function(e) {
  console.log(e + " (this.answer = " + this.answer + ")");
}, o);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking on what @NinaScholz commented, perhaps you can use variables and any changes would be set in those instead of changing the loop.

```js
function someFn(item, array2){
  array2.push(item, array2);
}

var arrayItems1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var arrayItems2 = [];

var firstIndex = 1;
var lastIndex = 5;
var i = 0;

for (i = firstIndex; i < lastIndex; i++){
     someFn(arrayItems1[i], arrayItems2);
}

alert(arrayItems2.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply some kind of implementation of the iterator pattern.

```
var Iterator = function (list, position) {
  return {
    isNext: function () {
      return position + 1 < list.length;
    },
    isDefined: function () {
      return (position < list.length && position >= 0);
    },
    element: function () {
      return list[position];
    },
    position: function () {
      return position;
    },
    moveNext: function () {
      if (this.isNext()) { return Iterator(list, position + 1); }
      return Iterator([], 0);
    }      
}

Iterator.forEach = function (action, iterator, length) {
  var counter = 0;
  while (counter < length && iterator.isDefined()) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    action(iterator.element(), iterator.position());
    iterator = iterator.moveNext();
  }

  return iterator;
}
```

And then have an iterator to use for going over the list and keep the state of the last iteration over a list.

```
var list = [1, 3, 5, 3, 6];
var iterator = Iterator(list, 0);

iterator = Iterator.forEach(function (element, index) {
  console.log(element, index);
}, iterator, 3);

//1 0
//3 1
//5 2

Iterator.forEach(function (element, index) {
   console.log(element, index);              
}, iterator, 5);

//3 3
//6 4
```

Answer (score -1):

[`array.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) to get the iterator, `.next()` it and use it.

```js
let ar=[1,2,3,4]

var _;for(let a of(_=ar.values(),_.next(),_)){
  console.log(a)
}
```